# SPARK : Data frame Select expression failed to do append operation if both single quote and double quote present in the value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My scenario explained  below:- (The below experiment tried with Spark Shell)

I have a Data frame which contains ,customer Id and customer Name columns .Now I want to perform an append operation on it through Spark UDF.

**Example given below :-**

```
case class Customer(customerId: Int, customerName: String)

val x = sc.parallelize(Array(Customer(123, "User1"),Customer(456, "User2")))

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(x)

df.registerTempTable("df")
```

Above steps will create Data Frame and register in the name of "df" .

Now register Spark UDF(append)

```
sqlContext.udf.register("append", (s: String, p1: String) => { if (s != null) s + p1 else p1 })
```

Then I'm assigning the value into a variable. This value needs to be append with customerName column values

```
val appendString = "'\""
```

Here my append string contains both single(') quote and double quote(") in the value ,if I try to execute below spark query :-

```
sqlContext.sql(s"SELECT  append(`customerName`, $appendString) as `customerName APPEND` from df").show
```

Result will be a Parse exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.68] failure: identifier expected SELECT
>   append(`customerName`, '") as `customerName APPEND` from df
>                                                                      ^
>           at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.AbstractSparkSQLParser.parse(AbstractSparkSQLParser.scala:36)

My Expected output is

**customerName APPEND**

User1'"

User2'"

**My finding are given below :-**

If there is only single quotes present in the value, then I can successfully execute query like below:-

```
val appendString = "'" 

sqlContext.sql(s"""SELECT  append(`customerName`, \"$appendString\") as `customerName APPEND` from df""").show
```

If there is only double quote present in the value,then I can successfully  execute query like below:-

```
val appendString = "\"" 

sqlContext.sql(s"""SELECT  append(`customerName`, '$appendString') as `customerName APPEND` from df""").show
```

But if there are single(') quote and double quote(") present in the same string ,I was not able to find a possible to way to execute this using Spark Data Frame Select expression API.

My spark version is  1.6.0

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [String Interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) to fetch the value from a String. But to make your UDF work first you need to change your `appendString` value as

```
val appendString = """"'\"""""
```

It will save `"'\""` value to appendString variable, which you need to pass to your UDF. Notice that you need to skip `"` and wrap `'\"` around double quotes to make it a valid String character for your UDF. Now use following statement to get your result

```
sqlContext.sql(s"""SELECT  append(customerName, $appendString) as `customerName APPEND` from df""").show

//output
+-------------------+
|customerName APPEND|
+-------------------+
|            User1'"|
|            User2'"|
+-------------------+
```